# How do I prevent Windows from presenting software RAID discs as a single volume?

Tags: raid, software-raid

Here's my issue:  I had a server's software RAID fail.  I don't believe it's the hard drives, as they are brand new RE drives from Western Digital and the RAID software said that 2 dives had failed.

So, I took these SATA drives out and hooked them up to my Windows 7 desktop on a couple free SATA ports.  None of my SATA ports are configured for RAID.  They are all just AHCI.  The BIOS sees both drives independently, but when I boot into Windows, it shows them as a single logical unit.

I want to run RAID Reconstructor on them from Runtime.org, but I need the OS to see them as 2 separate drives to do that.  Does anyone know how I can keep Windows from being so "smart" about these RAID drives?

Comment: Does Windows 7 see this single logical drive as degraded?

Comment: You don't want to get a RAID controller card? Did you run HDD sector scans and diagnostics on the drives independently to make sure they're good? Hitachi has a lower DOA and failure rate than WD. HGST is supposed to be more reliable than WD too, even though its a WD company heh.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming its a Windows 7 or Windows server 2008 software RAID 1.
It may be a fault of the software raid controller, which marked the drives as failed because they fell off-sync for some reason.

Run *diskpart > break* on a raided volume to disassemble the RAID - then the data on them should be readable, if those drives aren't actually broken.

additional info:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Windows_Server_2008_Mirrored_(RAID_1)_Volumes#Breaking_and_Removing_Mirrored_Sets

> A Windows Server 2008 mirror may be broken (which creates two separate
>   and independent volumes containing identical data) or removed (which
>   removes the data on the mirror leaving free space on the designated
>   mirror disk). To break a mirror from the Disk Management snap-in right
>   click on one of the volumes in the set in graphical view and select
>   Break Mirrored Volume from the pop-up menu. To break a mirror set from
>   the command line use the break command, specifying one of the two
>   disks in the mirrored set: DISKPART>break disk=2

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to your answer, please?